# `adb shell service call isms` message size limit

Tags: adb, sms

I am using the following:

```
adb shell service call isms 7 i32 0 s16 "com.android.mms.service" s16 "%num%" s16 "null" s16 "'%THISMSG%'" s16 "null" s16 "null"
```

(in a batch file)

Wondering if there is a limit on the message size. I did some experiments and when I add a few more characters, the sending fails. It seems that the limit is 70 (?) chars.

When the text size is up to 70 chars, the sending works fine!

I used just simple characters.

Any info available?

Comment: AFAIK, it depends on the character encoding, as per [Twilio Docs' explanation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-sms-character-limit#:~:text=The%20character%20limit%20for%20a,are%20limited%20to%2070%20characters.)